# Change a property value in service angularjs

Tags: angularjs, data-binding

I have a drop down list in my registration form for the customer type.

I would like to render a specific layout based on the value from this drop down list. For this purpose I have created a customer directive:

```
gasStation.directive('createMenuTree',['$log','customerType',function($log, customerType){

    var template;

    $log.debug(customerType.getCustomerType()+ ' from directive');

    if (customerType.getCustomerType() == 'REGULAR')  {template = 'dashboard/regular_dashboard.html';}
    if (customerType.getCustomerType() == 'BUSINESS') {template = 'dashboard/business_dashboard.html';}

    return{
        templateUrl: template
    }; }]);
```

And my controller:

```
gasStation.controller('registrationController', ['$scope','$window','customerType', function($scope, $window, customerType){

    $scope.ProcessRegistration = function(){
        var url = "http://" + $window.location.host +'/pages/index.html#'+'/dashboard';
        $window.location.href = url;      
        customerType.setCustomerType($scope.customerType); 
    };    

}]);
```

And my service:

```
gasStation.service('customerType',function(){

    var customerType;

    return{

        getCustomerType: function(){ return customerType; },
        setCustomerType: function(type){ customerType = type; }

    };
});
```

However, based on the documentation, all service object are singletons.

The question is: how can I update the service variable `customerType` based on the selected value from the drop down list?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Factory method instead of Service as below -

```js
app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
  app.factory('customerType',function(){

    var customerType;

    return{

        getCustomerType: function(){ return customerType; },
        setCustomerType: function(type){ customerType = type; }

    };
});
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','customerType', function($scope,customerType){

  $scope.cType = 'Retail';

  $scope.update = function(val){
    customerType.setCustomerType(val);
    $scope.cType = customerType.getCustomerType(val);
  };
 
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">



<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="t">
  <button type="button" ng-click="update(t)"> Change</button>

  <pre>Customer Type : {{cType}}</pre>
</div>
```

This is just a POC for updating the service value. you can implement similar thing in dropdown.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Would this approach work if redirection is being enabled?

Comment: @mr.M - didn't get your question. Do you mean if the updated value will persist even after page reload?

Comment: yeap. I have a redirection to another pager where the directive is being conditionally rendered.

Comment: @mr.M - in case of different page you will have to persist data at server side or in local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have your dropdown like this

```
<select ng-model='model.customerType' ng-change='customerChanged()' ..... />
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.customerChanged = function(){
   customerType.customerType = model.customerType;
}
```

That's it.

Comment: I have tried your suggested approach, but no luck. I did the following: I submitted the form with the first type of the customer -> directive was rendered properly. But, when I changed the customer type then the directive was rendered as if I chose the first option instead of the second one.